# How to find the default file format associations & applications menu

Tags: files, default

Where can I find the default file format associations menu?
Ex. I would like to open all .doc files with Microsoft Word, instead of archive manager.  This is a constant pain!

Comment: I posted a answer here:[file associations office playonlinux][1]
  


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/116002/how-to-set-file-associations-with-playonlinux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to right click on the word document, then go into the Open With tab, and then pick the program you want:

[image]