# how to set file associations with PlayOnLinux?

Tags: playonlinux

I have installed MS Office 2010 using PlayOnLinux. i want to associate the .docx files to Playonlinux. Could you please tell me how to do that? Playonlinux does not show up in "Open With" options. I am using UBuntu 12.04 Beta. There is no place that I can find, where I can add a custom command.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Update: PlayOnLinux have finally added this feature so you do not need to do this manually any more! **But you still have to add `"$(echo "$@" | sed -e 's:/*/:\\:g')"` in the end.**

First make sure you are showing hidden files by open homefolder. Click on edit then preferences and tick the bar. **Close the window.**
Then you type the command

```
sudo nautilus
```

Type in your password. Then you will need click yourself to top of disk. Then go to usr/share/applications. There try to find the word icon. If you dont finde it then copy the icon from the desktop and paste it in the folder. Right click on the icon you just pasted and click on properties. Change the "command" to

```
playonlinux --run "Microsoft Word 2010" z:%f
```

(Make sure to teave the " in) For Powerpoint you just change "`Word`" to "`Powerpoint`" And if you are running office 2007 you just change "`2011`" to "`2007`"
Do this with all the icons you want to set file associations for. Then **close the Window.**

**If you have the updated program start from here:**

Then open home folder. Click on .playonlinux/shortcuts
There you will find different files named  exel powerpoint and word. Open one with notepad.
The file should look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ "$PLAYONLINUX" = "" ] && exit 0
source "$PLAYONLINUX/lib/sources"
export WINEPREFIX="/home/leo/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/Office2010"
export WINEDEBUG="-all"
#POL_Log=Microsoft Office 2010_1336312516
cd "/home/leo/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/Office2010/drive_c/./Program Files/Microsoft Office/Office14"
POL_Wine "EXCEL.EXE"  $@
```

In the end change `$@` to

```
"$(echo "$@" | sed -e 's:/*/:\\:g')"
```

(leave " in!!) You have to do this with every application you want to set associations to.

Now go to the file you want to open click open with and other applications then show other applications and you should see word and powerpoint. Click on it and is should start. You have to repeat this with all the apps you want to set associations to.
Hope it will work!

Update: PlayOnLinux have finally added this feature so you do not need to do this manually any more! But you still have to add `"$(echo "$@" | sed -e 's:/*/:\\:g')"` in the end.

Comment: excellent! it works like a charm. I will add this how to to my blog! :)

Comment: Glad it helped! It took me for ever to figure it out...

Answer (score 6):

The Easiest solution:

Open the nautilus or other file browser,
Click with the right bottom of mouse on a doc(x) file, 
properties, Open With, Add Application, Use a custom command, and use:

**playonlinux --run "Microsoft Word 2007" '"z:%f"'**

Do the same for other filetypes as Excel, Powerpoint, and others..

Answer (score 0):

My "dirtiest" and "securiest" hack!

**EXAMPLE**

```
export POL_IgnoreWineErrors=True && /usr/share/playonlinux4/playonlinux --run "hlmv (p2mv)" $(echo $(winepath -w "%F") | sed 's,\\,\\\\,g' | sed 's, ,\\ ,g')
```

**EXPLANATION**

Adds the drive letter and adjust for a M$ Windows path...

```
winepath -w "%F"
```

Escapes the bars and spaces; conforms to the Wine standards...

```
sed 's,\\,\\\\,g' | sed 's, ,\\ ,g'
```

**Thanks!**

Answer (score -3):

To make skp files open with playonlinux : Sketchup 2017 ...
Right-click a skp file in Thunar, select 'Open with Other Application' , select Playonlinux , also check the 'Use as default for this kind of file' and click [Open] button.

Playonlinux will say it's not setup for this file type.

On playonlinux, select 'Settings' > 'File Associations' from menu,
click [New] , it will ask you what extension? — type 'skp' (no quotes), and click [OK] button.
Click on the new listing for skp created in the table, use the selection menu at the bottom next to 'Assigned program' to choose 'SketchUp 2017'
and click [Apply] button.

It will say 'You must restart playonlinux for the changes to take effect"
Click [OK] button.

Close playonlinux app, it will ask "Are you sure you want to close all playonlinux windows?"
Click [Yes] button.

... The next time you try to open the skp file, it will work!

---

** This example uses XFCE desktop environment, your file manager might be something other than Thunar. **

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?