# Kubuntu and Play On Linux, File Associations

Tags: wine, kubuntu, playonlinux

I am trying to associate files with Notepad++ running under PlayOnLinux on Kubuntu 13.10.

(Yes, I *am* aware that there are *plenty* of equivalent programs that may be used in Kubuntu.  The reason I want to use Notepad++ is because we are using it at university and I want consistency)

I have followed the instructions in [this article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116002/how-to-set-file-associations-with-playonlinux), right up to the point where it says to open with other applications.  But I do not see Notepad++ listed *anywhere* on the list.  How do I add it to the list of applications (categories) in Kubuntu?

Comment: How do you normally open it - and where is the executable exe located?

Comment: What are you referring to when you say "How do I normally open it"?  If you mean Notepad++, it runs on PlayOnLinux, so I either go into PlayOnLinux and open it there, or I use the desktop shortcut.  I copied this shortcut to /usr/share/applications as explained in the article.  The .exe itself is in (myhomedrive)/PlayOnLinux's virtual drives/NotepadPlusPlus/drive_c/Program Files/Notepad++/

Comment: As an update, if I right-click on a file, and go Open With > Other... I can then browse to the location above and choose Notepad++.exe.  But I don't want to have to do that every time I open something like an HTML, SQL or PHP file for editing.  Can I add Notepad++ to the list of known applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the Notepad++ .desktop launcher file - the one you put in `/usr/share/applications` - it will look like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Notepad++
Comment=PlayOnLinux
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux --run "Notepad++" %F
Icon=/home/USERNAME/.PlayOnLinux//icones/full_size/Notepad++
Name[fr_FR]=Notepad++
MimeType=application/x-cgi;application/x-httpd-php3;application/x-httpd-php4;application/x-httpd-php5;application/x-javascript;application/x-perl;application/x-php;application/x-python;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;text/css;text/html;text/javascript;text/mathml;text/plain;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-diff;text/x-dsrc;text/x-dtd;text/x-java;text/x-javascript;text/x-pascal;text/x-perl;text/x-php;text/x-python;text/x-sql;text/xml;
StartupWMClass=notepad++.exe
Categories=
```

add/change these lines:

```
Categories=Text;Editor;Plaintext;Write;GTK;Development;IDE;
MimeType=text/plain;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-java;text/x-dsrc;text/x-pascal;text/x-perl;text/x-python;application/x-php;application/x-httpd-php3;application/x-httpd-php4;application/x-httpd-php5;application/xml;text/html;text/css;text/x-sql;text/x-diff;
```

Then right click on the file you want, and go to 'Properties' then to the 'Open With' tab: 
 [image: You can find Notepad++ and]

You can then find Notepad++, and either 'Add' or 'Set is as Default'

Then you can open it with Notepad++ as default
[image]

Comment: It worked! You sir, are a genius!  Actually I also noticed that now if I create, say, a .html file on my desktop and right click and go Open With, Notepad++ appears there at the bottom of the list so I don't even have to go "Other" any more!

Comment: Also, of you are using Dolphin, the KDE file manager, you just need to go to 'Open With' and at the top enter `/usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux --run "Notepad++" %F` - dunno how you set that as default though - glad it worked, mark it as answered if you think it is.